# To apply for appointment centre service fee of Rs.4095 that is paid twice?

Tags: visas, uk, refunds, payment

An appointment was made and paid for in United Kingdomn. However, before a note could be made of the reference number or print the appointment confirmation the pc crashed. I was not able to go bac to that confirmation page again.

However, the appointment was attended and proof of payment was asked for. So unable to provide the receipt of the payment the applicant had to pay again the same amount of Rs.4095. Now I am looking to get a refund from the vfs but a simple matter is made so complicated! How do one go about it. I can provide evidence of the UK payment by way of paymwent having been made through my Visa Debit card.

Answer (score 1):

Visa, MasterCard, Maestro, and Visa Electron debit cardholders can use the Chargeback scheme to get a refund if something goes wrong when you spend on your card.

Chargeback covers purchases of almost any value made on your card. You can use it to get your money back if:

- A purchase does not arrive
- The company you buy from goes bust
- Goods or services are not as described or are in an unsatisfactory condition
- You are charged more than agreed for a purchase or are charged more than once
- Your card is used fraudulently

To make a Chargeback claim you will need to contact your card provider within their time limit - usually 120 days after discovering the problem.